# Backwards compatibility for QGIS 3.2.1 Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have created multiple models using the Processing Modeler in QGIS 2.18.15. However, I could not open these .model files in the user interface for the Graphical/Processing Modeler in QGIS 3.2.1, which seems to only accept .model3 or .MODEL3 files. Also, there is an option to save the (.model) file as a Python (.py) file in QGIS 2.18.15.

Is there a way that I can make either the (.model) or (.py) files from QGIS 2.18.15 compatible for QGIS 3.2.1 Graphical/Processing modeler? Since the alternative to that would be to re-create the Processing Modeler manually from scratch.